# Is there not a Google API Key for Elevation Service?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-elevation-api

I am trying to execute [Elevation Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-simple) sample. I created an API key using my google account, then clicked on "YOUR_API_KEY" link at the bottom of the "JAVASCRIPT + HTML" section, this helped me select an API key from my applications and then was inserted. I then copied and pasted the code on my machine and ran the sample, however I get the following error:

> This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: *InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError*.

Has anyone had success in executing Google Elevation Service requests using fee API key?

Here is the code I tried to execute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Elevation service</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 63.333, lng: -150.5},  // Denali.
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Add a listener for the click event. Display the elevation for the LatLng of
  // the click inside the infowindow.
  map.addListener('click', function(event) {
    displayLocationElevation(event.latLng, elevator, infowindow);
  });
}

function displayLocationElevation(location, elevator, infowindow) {
  // Initiate the location request
  elevator.getElevationForLocations({
    'locations': [location]
  }, function(results, status) {
    infowindow.setPosition(location);
    if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
      // Retrieve the first result
      if (results[0]) {
        // Open the infowindow indicating the elevation at the clicked position.
        infowindow.setContent('The elevation at this point <br>is ' +
            results[0].elevation + ' meters.');
      } else {
        infowindow.setContent('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      infowindow.setContent('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Update:

I created a browser key and now the code works! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you using a server key or a browser key?  [The posted code works for me on my server with my (browser) key](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_ElevationsServiceWithKey.html)

Comment: I created a server key by going to (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/get-api-key#key)

Comment: It needs to be a browser key for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 (the way you are using it)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a browser key with the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Elevation Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation).  That is what is being used in the Elevation Service in the code you posted.

```
var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
// Initiate the location request
elevator.getElevationForLocations({
  'locations': [location]
}, function(results, status) {
  infowindow.setPosition(location);
  if (status === google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
    // Retrieve the first result
    if (results[0]) {
      // Open the infowindow indicating the elevation at the clicked position.
      infowindow.setContent('The elevation at this point <br>is ' +
          results[0].elevation + ' meters.');
    } else {
      infowindow.setContent('No results found');
    }
  } else {
    infowindow.setContent('Elevation service failed due to: ' + status);
  }
});
```

[working example with browser key](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_ElevationsServiceWithKey.html)

If you use the [Google Maps Elevation Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro), then you need a server key.

Comment: I have accepted and upvoted your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

## You must enable elevation api in Google before you use it

[image]